# Chinese character cannot be read export to pdf from crystal report (parameter)

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, pdf, crystal-reports

I am using crystal report viewer to print and export the report to pdf file. I realized when printing chinese character, it will show a box instead of the word it self.

The code is how I assign the data to the parameter in crystal report.

```
ReportDocument reportData = new ReportDocument();
            string reportPath = Server.MapPath("IncidentReport.rpt");
            reportData.Load(reportPath);

            //get data from database
            string sqlcommand = "SELECT TICKETNO, TO_CHAR(REPORTDATE,'dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM') AS REPORTDATE, STATUS, SEVERITY,CATEGORY,ASSIGNEE,INCIDENTDESC,INCIDENTDETAIL,INCIDENTTYPE,ANALYSIS,SOLUTION,ATTACHMENT,TO_CHAR(CREATEDATE,'dd-mm-yyyy') AS CREATEDATE,CREATEUSERID,TO_CHAR(UPDATEDATE,'dd-mm-yyyy') AS UPDATEDATE, UPDATEUSERID FROM TICKET WHERE TICKETNO = '" + Session["ticketNoR"] + "' ";
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            readdata.selectdata(ds, sqlcommand);

            //set parameter
            reportData.SetParameterValue("ticketNo", (String)Session["ticketNoR"]);
            reportData.SetParameterValue("reportedDate", ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["REPORTDATE"].ToString());
            reportData.SetParameterValue("Status", ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["STATUS"].ToString());
            reportData.SetParameterValue("severity", ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SEVERITY"].ToString());
            reportData.SetParameterValue("category", ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CATEGORY"].ToString());
            reportData.SetParameterValue("assignee", ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ASSIGNEE"].ToString());
            reportData.SetParameterValue("attachment", ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ATTACHMENT"].ToString());
            reportData.SetParameterValue("type", ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["INCIDENTTYPE"].ToString());
            reportData.SetParameterValue("incidentDesc", ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["INCIDENTDESC"].ToString());
            reportData.SetParameterValue("incidentDetail", ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["INCIDENTDETAILS"].ToString());
            reportData.SetParameterValue("Analysis", ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ANALYSIS"].ToString());
            reportData.SetParameterValue("Solution", ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SOLUTION"].ToString());
```

I am using oracle 11g as database and asp.net C# for coding.

Everything looks good in browser but when export to pdf file then it become none-readable character already. ( only parameter that i use C# to pass the value to it cannot show chinese. text object are shown pretty good.

English characters are well display but for chinese character is not working.
Anyone have any idea on this? 
Your comment and suggestion is much appreciated!

Comment: Which font are you using. Check the font is installed correctly in the WEB SERVER

Comment: Goto Control panel ->Font Settings-> Uncheck Hide fonts based on language settings.

Comment: @vcs: didn't work on WinServer 2008R2 --> is there a reboot necessary?